# Kendo TreeView Move Parent nodes to change the Sort Order but not allow a Parent to be dragged under a Child node

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-treeview

I have Kendo TreeView in which parent nodes have children nodes.

Rules that I want are that a user can

1. Drag parent node above or below the current position , thus change the sort order
2. Not allow a parent to be dragged onto another parent node
3. Not allow a parent to be dragged onto any child node
4. DO allow a child node item to be dragged under another parent node

I certainly prefer javascript or jquery

This code simply prevents all parent nodes from being dragged and thus it is not want I am wanting.  Anyone have any samples on this?

```
 $(".k-treeview").data("kendoTreeView").bind("dragstart", function (e) {
    if ($(e.sourceNode).parentsUntil(".k-treeview", ".k-item").length == 0) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE from answer**

Seems that almost all the code it working correcting from the answer if I place it in my `$(document).ready(function() { ...`

But If I place that code under the **onDrop** is does not get called up.

e.g.

```
  var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                                    expanded: true,
                                    dragAndDrop: true,
                                    select: onSelect,
                                    loadOnDemand: false,
                                    dataSource: homogeneous,
                                    dataTextField: "ReportGroupName",
                                    template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()) //,
                                    ,
                                    onDrop: function(e) {
                                        kendoTreeView = $(".k-treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
                                        kendoTreeView.bind("drag", function (e) {

                                            //Check if we're trying to add the node as a child
                                            var dropAsChild = $(e.dropTarget).hasClass("k-in k-state-hover");

                                            var sourceDataItem = kendoTreeView.dataItem(e.sourceNode);
                                            var destinationDataItem = kendoTreeView.dataItem(e.dropTarget);

                                            if ($(e.sourceNode).is(e.dropTarget)) {
                                                //Dropping on itself
                                                e.setStatusClass("k-denied");
                                            } else if (destinationDataItem && !dropAsChild) {
                                                //Dropping as a sibling... that's ok if it's the same parent
                                                if (sourceDataItem.parent().uid != destinationDataItem.parent().uid) {
                                                    //Not the same parent
                                                    e.setStatusClass("k-denied");
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                e.setStatusClass("k-denied");
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

**IMAGE** 
Here is an image  red arrow is pointing at child that I was to move to another parent ( to be a child of that parent with blue arrow)

[image]

Comment: Note that it should be `drop`... not `onDrop`

Comment: Ok,  I changed to drop:  ,  then I noticed your answer shows  "drag"    both  drop and drag seem to give the same behavior   - all but not allowing the children of a parent to be dragged onto another parent,  thx in advance     -  Would the else statement be a good place to nest in an if statement for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the `dragstart` event is that it won't provide you the drop target as it's to early in the event sequence.

The best way to do achieve this would be to deny the drop action based on the source and destination node.  You can do this by calling the `setStatusClass` (with a `k-denied`) on the event object passed to the `drag` event.

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    expanded: true,
    dragAndDrop: true,
    select: onSelect,
    loadOnDemand: false,
    dataSource: homogeneous,
    dataTextField: "ReportGroupName",
    template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
    drag: function (e) {
        //Check if we're trying to add the node as a child
        var kendoTreeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
        var dropAsChild = $(e.dropTarget).hasClass("k-in k-state-hover");

        var sourceDataItem = kendoTreeView.dataItem(e.sourceNode);
        var destinationDataItem = kendoTreeView.dataItem(e.dropTarget);

        if ($(e.sourceNode).is(e.dropTarget)) {
            //Dropping on itself
            e.setStatusClass("k-denied");
        } else if (destinationDataItem && !dropAsChild) {
            //Dropping as a sibling... that's ok if it's the same parent
            if (sourceDataItem.parent().uid != destinationDataItem.parent().uid) {
                //Not the same parent
                e.setStatusClass("k-denied");
            }
        } else {
            e.setStatusClass("k-denied");
        }
    }
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

I can't test the code above right now so they may be some error... I'm sure you'll still understand the logic behind it.

Comment: I took your sample where you were using the treeView `drag` event.  Just replace your code with the code above.

Comment: Ok, I see that I can put under my  `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Oh, so I gather you are saying this code CAN be placed within my code `var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                                        expanded: true,`

Comment: So i'm looking into the code, trying to figure out what I need to change in order to move a child item from 1 parent node onto another parent node , that part i desparately need

Comment: You said that the code *Do allow a child node item to be dragged under another parent node*...

Comment: Also, I was trying to add your code withing    onDrop: function(e) {   }   but that does not work

Comment: Let me update the question with the Code , and yes I should really have a jsfiddle for this

Comment: I updated the question to match the data provided in your question update.

Comment: Ok, is the code different?   ( other than you saying the drop ) ?    I also added an image    thx

Comment: Ok, I created a fiddle and I'm going to create new question that I will post here with 2 issues on drag and drop that I'm trying to solve  , thx in advance

Comment: Here is my question.   BTW where do you find all the events etc.. with Kendo,  I'm just too new to Kendo ...      Here is my new question :    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296079/drag-and-drop-kendo-treeview-to-allow-child-to-be-dragged-onto-empty-parent-node      thx again

Answer (score 0):

We can check e.statusClass in drag event. So cancel dragging if element is adding as a child. Made some changes in The_Black_Smurf code. Below code works for me

```
drag: function (e) {
    //Check if are we adding node as a child
    if(e.statusClass == "i-plus") {
      e.setStatusClass("k-i-cancel"); //Cancel drop
      return;
    }
    var kendoTreeView = $("#treeViewAttr").data("kendoTreeView");
    var sourceDataItem = kendoTreeView.dataItem(e.sourceNode);
    var destinationDataItem = kendoTreeView.dataItem(e.dropTarget);
  
    if (destinationDataItem) { 
      if (sourceDataItem.parent()[0].uid != destinationDataItem.parent()[0].uid) { 
        e.setStatusClass("k-i-cancel");
      }
    }        
  }
```

In my kendo treeview version classes naming was different, please read below class names and define class names as per your kendo version.

As per API reference of kendoTreeView drag event

### Pre-defined status classes are:

**k-insert-top**

- Indicates that the item will be inserted on top.

**k-insert-middle**

- Indicates that the item will be inserted in the
  middle.

**k-insert-bottom**

- Indicates that the item will be inserted at
  the bottom.

**k-add**

- Indicates that the item will be added/appended.

**k-denied**

- Indicates an invalid operation. Using this class will
  automatically make the drop operation invalid, so there will be no
  need to call setValid(false) in the drop event.

**This is most important:-**

Please note that from version 2016.3.914 the naming convention for pre-defined status classes is k-i-className. Since version 2017.1.118 the following status classes are used: `k-i-insert-up, k-i-insert-down, k-i-insert-middle, k-i-plus, k-i-cancel`.

Note that status classes are returned without the `k-` prefix by `e.statusClass`, but this prefix is required when setting a predefined status class via `e.setStatusClass`. A prefix is not required if setting a custom status CSS class.